# Javascript to time speech

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, dom-events, html5-audio

I'm looking for a way to time the input it takes for someone to speak a block of text on a webpage only using HTML5.

I've looked into the x-webkit-speech and can record the sentence but am looking a way to time the input for instance "onwebkitspeechstart"

```
<input id="speech" type="text" speech x-webkit-speech onwebkitspeechstart="alert('Timer Start');" onwebkitspeechend="alert('Timer End');"/>
```

Also does anyone know how to change the amount of time the webkit speech waits before it thinks the speech has ended to allow for longer pauses between sentences.

I've done a lot of Googling on the subject but can't find a list of supported attributes/events.

Comment: Apparently not allowed to "Self-Answer" but I figured this out.
Taking a step back this was pretty simple:

    <input id="speech" type="text" speech x-webkit-speech 
        onClick="StartTimer();"
        onwebkitspeechchange="StopTimer();"/>

Then having two javascripts functions to get the time and then do a compare:


   var timeStart;
   var timeEnd
   
   function StartTimer(){
    timeStart = new Date();
   }
   
   function StopTimer() {
    timeEnd = new Date();
    //get the number of seconds it took to record.
    var duration = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 1000;
   }

Answer (score 0):

From a comment from the Original Poster who thought incorrectly that  they were not allowed to "Self-Answer" but did figured this out.

> Taking a step back this was pretty simple:

```
<input id="speech" type="text" speech x-webkit-speech onClick="StartTimer();" onwebkitspeechchange="StopTimer();"/>
```

> Then having two Javascripts functions to get the time and then do a compare:

```
var timeStart;
var timeEnd
function StartTimer(){
    timeStart = new Date();
}
function StopTimer() {
    timeEnd = new Date(); //get the number of seconds it took to record.
    var duration = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 1000;
}
```